# can't seem to figure this out

Tags: functions

A function is given as:    $$f(x) = 8 + x + x^2 − x^3$$

Find the local maximum and minimum values of the function and the value of x at which each occurs. State each answer correct to two decimal places.

maximum: (  ,  ) 
minimum: (  ,  )

Comment: Well, this seems like a routine calculus problem.  What have you tried?  What goes wrong?

Comment: **Hint:** local and global maximums and minimums can only occur where the derivative is equal to zero.  That is to say if $x$ is a maximum or minimum then $f'(x)=0$.  (*the converse is not true.  It is possible for $f'(x)=0$ despite $x$ not being a maximum or minimum*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x) = -3x^2+2x+1 = -(3x + 1)(x - 1)= 0 \iff x = -1/3, 1$, and $f''(1) = -6x+2|_{x=1} = - 4 < 0, f''(-1/3) = -6x+2|_{x = -1/3} = 4>0$. Thus the $2$nd derivative test shows that the local max attained at $x = 1$,and the local min attained at $x = -1/3$. Can you find $f(1)$ and $f(-1/3)$ respectively which will be the max and min of $f$ locally ? I hope this helps...